# Abort Evaluation in Mathematica 12

Tags: general-utilities

Aborting evaluation usign menu Evaluation -> Abort Evaluation, or equivalently 'Alt + .' key shortcut doesn't work in my Mathematica 12.0.0.0. Is it a known bug?

Comment: Please always provide a complete reproducible example. What are you try to interrupt? Some computations (very few) are not interruptible. One can also mess up the system in certain ways that would practically prevent interruption, such as Shadowray's example of overwhelming the front end. I guess the same would happen if one reserved a lot of memory quickly and cause the system to keep swapping.  All that said: *Mathematica 12.0 does not behave any differently than 11.3 in this respect on my machine (macOS)*.

Comment: I've been having no trouble aborting evaluations with my spiffy new installation of v 12.0.0, on a rather ageing Mac Pro.  I tend to use the menu rather than the keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm this issue.

For example, the following code will hang the front end of v12.0.0.

```
(* !!! SAVE ALL YOUR WORK BEFORE RUNNING THIS !!! *)
For[i = 0, True, i++, Print[i]]
```

As noted by Lucas in comments, one can use Task Manager/Activity Monitor to terminate WolframKernel process (but **not** Mathematica process). This way one will loose all evaluation results, but has a chance to un-hang the front end and save the notebook.

Comment: Overwhelming the FE would make interruption difficult in all versions, not just 12.0.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, not being able tp stop `Print` in a long loop has always been one of the most annoying and dangerous things. Unfortunately, WRI missed the opportunity to fix this when rewriting(?) the FrontEnd for macos. (I hope there was a bit more to the 64-bit conversion than just resetting a compiler flag (thus a 65-bit conversion ;). otherwise this could have been done a long time ago.)

Comment: Note that in most cases the front-end can be recovered by simply terminating the kernel process via Task Manager/Activity Monitor/... (one of the nice things about having separate processes) - while this will reset your computations, your unsaved work can often be saved

Comment: I have had mathematica *just shut off* recently, twice...on my work station though, it a regular with my laptop, this is expected, but not the specially parted workstation! I wonder if these are similar issues? Thanks for the task manager solution!